# Windows 10 has caused VBA MailItem run-time error

Tags: excel, vba, windows-10

I have just updated to `Windows 10` and now the following `VBA code` from an Excel sheet causes a run-time error:

```
Dim aOutlook As Object

....

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

aEmail.To = "emailaddress"
```

Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)': 
Method 'To' of object'_MailItem' failed

It is the same for Excel 2003 and Excel 2013. Can anyone suggest what needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: How is aOutlook declared? Have a look at this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/270589).

Comment: Dim aOutlook As Object - at the very beginning as a global

Comment: It looks like the error above then. They're saying you should use early-binding (i.e. add the reference to Outlook object model in the project before and declare directly as the proper type, instead of assigning the type lately).

Comment: Reading your code though, I think the early-binding should be rather done on "aEmail".

Comment: Thanks - you seem to have spotted the problem (I got nothing when I searched for that error number!!) Now I need to figure out what early-binding is :)

Comment: Richard, the idea is the following: when you do "late-binding", you 1) First, declare a variable as a generic object; 2) Then, assign to this object a precise type. Example: `Dim app As Object ; Set app = CreateObject("object.type")`. You are binding your variable "lately". With "early-binding", you add the reference to your project (e.g. add Outlook library), hence you 1) Declare your variable directly as the object you want; 2) create a new instance: `Dim app As Application; Set app = new Application`. Just adapt this generic example to your specific case.

Comment: I understand the problem and I think I understand the explanation of early and later binding. What I don't understand is how to declare an Outlook.Application variable early. Dim app As Application; Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") doesn't work. But I can't do Dim app As Outlook.Application .... so how do I early bind the variable to an Outlook application?

Comment: You can get started [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096).

Comment: But please note: you're having the error on the variable aEmail, and not aOutlook. So, most probably you will need to early bind that one as well in order to fix the issue.

Comment: Binding refers to telling the compiler what the object's type is.  You can do this at compile time ("early binding") or you can do this at run time ("late binding"). Just for fun: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for the error albeit a little unclear to me as to why it makes Excel behave like this:

[VBA - How to bind early Outlook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947793/vba-how-to-bind-early-outlook-application)