# Previously working code to assign email address generates error in Windows 10 upgrade: Method 'To' of object '_Mailitem' failed

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

This was working until the Windows 10 upgrade.

I get this error when trying to send an email from Excel:

> Run-time error '-2147417851 (80010105)': Method 'To' of object'_MailItem' failed

The code that caused this was:

```
Dim aOutlook As Object

....

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

aEmail.To = "emailaddress"
```

I have been told that it is because I am binding 'later' and that this is a bug (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096)). To bind 'early' I have tried the following:

```
Dim aOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim aMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set aOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set aEmail = aOutlook .CreateItem(olMailItem)

aEmail.To = "emailaddress"
aEmail.Display
```

Now I get the error:

> Microsoft Office Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action.

Before giving the same error as initially.

Comment: @KFichter Thanks. It worked in Windows 7. Did the upgrade and it stopped. A real pain! The .Text idea does not do anything.

Comment: @Bond The error occurs at the .To line.

Comment: Yes - error is Object Required now.

Comment: Oops sorry I was thinking about this the wrong way, my bad

Comment: and "emailaddress" is "emailaddress@whatever" I'm guessing?

Comment: What does `MsgBox TypeName(aEmail.To)` report? This should just be a string property, right?

Comment: @KFichter yes - email address is a full address.

Comment: @Bond - Yes a string

Comment: And i guess that you can manually start Outlook and create an email fine? What happens if you put the `aEmail.Display` line before the `aEmail.To` line?

Comment: Your early binding code works fine on the PC  that I upgraded y'day. Excel & Outlook 2010. Maybe use the Object Browser and look in the Outlook library to see if the `MailItem.To` property shows up as expected?

Comment: @ChipsLetten - Done that. Seems to all be there as expected.

Comment: What about my first comment - switching around the lines of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little strange but here is the answer. In my question for simplicity I put:

```
aEmail.To = "emailaddress"
```

but I actually had

```
aEmail.To = Cells(IntCurrentRow, 3)
```

where Cells(IntCurrentRow, 3) contained the email address. This seemed to be the problem. When I put the following it worked.

```
emailAddress = Cells(IntCurrentRow, 3)
aEMail.To = emailAddress
```

I am not sure why it wouldn't take the address directly but changing this has fixed the problem. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Yes, it happened with me also and I fixed with by similar way

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar but populating from a text box on a form.

`oMail.To = frmMain.txtRecepients` didn't work.  But,
`oMail.To = frmMain.txtRecepients.value` did.

I'm wondering if it wasn't trying to set the .to to the object instead of the value of the object.  Explicitly telling it to use the value seems to have fixed it.